# Google Maps not working with Ionic2 on Android

Tags: angular, google-maps, cordova, mobile, ionic2

I'm making a mobile app mostly following the examples in Ionic's doc pages. The aim is to get the user's latitude and longitude using android's Geolocation service, and display the position using the Google Maps service.

The Geolocation service works as intended and when given access to the device's location the latitude and longitude display on the application correctly and update every few seconds.

The Google Maps service is what I can't get working: I get only a light grey square and never any kind of update. The relevant code in question:

geo.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import {
 GoogleMaps,
 GoogleMap,
 GoogleMapsEvent,
 GoogleMapOptions,
 CameraPosition,
 MarkerOptions,
 Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'geo-contact',
  templateUrl: 'geo.html'
})
export class GeoPage implements OnInit {

  private watch;
  private lat=0;
  private lng=0;
  private map: GoogleMap;
  private mapReady=false;

  @ViewChild('mapCanvas') mapCanvas;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private geolocation: Geolocation) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
    this.watch.subscribe((data)=>{
        this.lat=data.coords.latitude;
        this.lng=data.coords.longitude;
        console.log('map ready? '+this.mapReady);
        if(this.mapReady){
            console.log('updating map position');
            this.map.moveCamera({
                target: {
                    lat: this.lat,
                    lon: this.lng
                },
                zoom: 8,
                tilt: 0
            });
        }
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad');
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap(){
    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
        camera: {
            target: {
                lat: this.lat,
                lon: this.lng
            },
            zoom: 8,
            tilt: 0
        },
        'mapType': 'MAP_TYPE_NORMAL'
    };

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create(this.mapCanvas.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    console.log('GoogleMaps.create called, waiting for GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY');

    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
            .then(()=>{
                console.log('GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY fired');
                this.mapReady=true;
                this.map.addMarker({
                    title: 'You\'re Here',
                    icon: 'blue',
                    animation: 'DROP',
                    position: {
                        lat: this.lat,
                        lng: this.lng
                    }
                })
                .then(marker => {
                    marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
                        .subscribe(()=>{
                            alert('clicked');
                        });
                });
            });

    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_LOADED)
            .then(()=>{
                console.log('GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_LOADED fired');
            });
  }
}
```

geo.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <div id="pre-navbar" style="display: inline-block;"><img src="./assets/imgs/logo-educacion.svg" style="height:40px;"></div>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      Maps
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <div *ngIf="lat!=0 && lng!=0">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>LATITUDE: {{lat}}</ion-item>
      <ion-item>LONGITUDE: {{lng}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="lat==0 || lng==0">
    <img src="./assets/imgs/Spinner-1s-200px.gif" style="height:40px;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:20px;">
  </div>
  <div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;" padding>
    <div #mapCanvas data-tap-disabled="true" style="min-width: 200px; min-height: 200px; height:80%;"></div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

As you can see I've added output to the console to log the state of `mapReady` which only changes to true once `GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY` has fired, and this is the output I get after a while, indicating it never does fire (the 'fetched quote' logs belong to a different view's functionality):

[image: js console output]

Small changes to the example code were made following different solutions like the use of `@ViewChild` and some juggling with the element's height property, but all I could do was get from nothing displaying to the light grey box. I'd really appreciate help with getting the Maps service to display properly.

Screen output:

[image: screen output showing the grey box]

**EDIT 1:**

I'm using Cordova 8.0.0 and running the app on mobile, debugging via `chrome://inspect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blank map is always api key problem.
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v1.4.0/TroubleShooting/Blank-Map/README.md

Check your all setting, or try new api keys.

Comment: I've restricted the api key to android apps as the link said, properly setting the package name and SHA-1 fingerprint, and the key seems to be correct in `package.json`, and still nothing... There's a difference with the case shown in that link though in that I don't even see the "Google" watermark, only a grey square

Comment: You need to enable both Google Maps Android API v2 and Google Maps SDK for iOS BEFORE generating api keys.

Comment: Try to generate new API keys, and reinstall the plugin.

Comment: Seems like the problem was generating the API key before adding the Google Maps API to my project. Maybe you should edit that into the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First a few checks:

1. Are you running in the browser or on a device / simulator? Because the GoogleMaps native plugin is only compatible with iOS and Android, not with the browser. In case your app has to work in the browser as well, have a look at the Google Maps Javascript SDK. A few good tutorials can be found here: https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/
2. Next run `ionic info` and check if you have the latest version of Cordova (currently 8.0.0). If not install or upgrade it. The current Google Maps Cordova plugin requires 7.1 or higher.
3. Then follow the instructions to install the Cordova plugin on: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/
4. In your code make sure to call `loadMap()` only when the platform is ready.
5. Note that there's currently a problem loading Cordova plugins when using live reload in Ionic. See: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1354

A minimal working example is:

```ts
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleMaps, GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  private map: GoogleMap;

  @ViewChild('mapCanvas') mapCanvas;

  constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.loadMap();
    });
  }

  loadMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create(this.mapCanvas.nativeElement);
    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
      .then(() => { console.log("Map ready"); });
  }
}
```

Comment: I can tell it doesn't run on browser so I've been running it on my device and debugging with chrome://inspect . As for the rest I won't have access to the development pc until monday so I'll update then, sorry!

Comment: Running Cordova 8.0.0, and yes I did follow those instructions to install the Maps plugin. As you can see in the code I'm calling loadMap() within ionViewDidLoad() as shown in that site's demo, so that should make sure the platform is correctly loaded?

Comment: No the view can be ready while the platform isn't. When the platform is ready, you can call native functions (which the maps plugin is). I have tested your code and it only works when you put loadMap() inside the platform.ready() event handler (as I pointed out above).

Comment: That's weird, I added the `Platform` import from `'ionic-angular'`, added `platform: Platform` to the constructor parameters and added your code with `console.log("platform ready")` as well inside ngOnInit(), and that gets logged yet there's no change in the plugin's behaviour...

Comment: I did some more research and updated my answer. See point 5 and the minimal working example.

Comment: I was assigned with an urgent, short-ish development so I can't check it right now, but as soon as I can go back to that project I'll get back to you. I really appreciate how much effort you're putting into helping me, I was stuck with this for a few days myself before I decided to ask for help

Comment: Well, I started a completely new application, erased the api key, recreated it and followed these steps, which made the GoogleMaps plugin work perfectly, but only after I messed around a bit with the css as in my original project. Apparently the problem was creating the key before adding the GoogleMaps API, which is the other answer in here so I'll be marking that as correct, but this is a thorough way of getting the app to work if you start from zero.